# How to Remove Nulls From List Then Add

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a list that is being populated from my database table and i'm trying to do a conversion later in the code. I am unable to do the conversion because the program reads the null values and says it's an illegal operation so I figure excluding the null values before they are even added to the list may be my best option. I know there are a lot of similar posts but i've tried a few of them with no luck.  It's for the list oldNames. I've tried `oldNames = oldNames.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m)).ToList();`,
                `oldNames.RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace);`,
                `oldNames.Where(i => i != null).ToList().Add(actualPDF);` But i need to get a count from them later and all three of those return 0 for the count `for (int i = 0; i < oldNames.Count; i++)`. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
List<string> oldNames = new List<string>(); //<----

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=x; Initial Catalog=x; Integrated Security=True;");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM x", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop;

    if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtFileLocation.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
    }

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(txtFileLocation.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (string val in files)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(val));
    }

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var actualPDF = row["x"].ToString();
        var namedFN = row["y"].ToString();
        var fileID = row["z"].ToString();
        var filesinFolder = listBox2.Items.ToString();

        listBox1.Items.Add(fileID);
        listBox4.Items.Add(namedFN);
        oldNames.Add(actualPDF); // <--- This List
    }
}
```

Comment: What is actually `NULL` here?  If there's `NULL` values coming from the database that you don't want to select then you can exclude them in the SQL query with something like `WHERE someColumn IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Could you clarify the last statement (about needing to get a count)? Are you saying the list is empty after excluding all nulls? Are there any non-nulls being added to the list?

Comment: I will try what you said @David and see if that works for me. Jacob no nothing is being added to the list at all, but when I use the original way seen in the code above all values are added to the list including nulls

Comment: Can you not simply get the row count from the datatable itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is to retrieve a count of non-null items from `row["x"]`, then perform the query on the database:

```
select count(*) from [table] where x is not null
```

Otherwise, exclude values from x where they are null in the original query:

```
select x, y, z from [table] where x is not null
```

Alternatively, the foreach loop should check for DBNull before performing any operations against the data row:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if(row["x"] == DBNull.Value || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row["x"].ToString())
    {
        continue;
    }

    var actualPDF = row["x"].ToString();
    var namedFN = row["y"].ToString();
    var fileID = row["z"].ToString();
    var filesinFolder = listBox2.Items.ToString();

    listBox1.Items.Add(fileID);
    listBox4.Items.Add(namedFN);

    oldNames.Add(actualPDF);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you